# Cakephp installation on WAMP missing files

Tags: cakephp, composer-php, wamp

I am running WAMP and it runs correctly. I installed composer apparently successfully, and also installed Cake with no errors. It created a cquiz project. When I go to the URL in my browser I see all of the text for the default cake page, but none of the css or images. It is looking for files, for example, /cquiz/css/cake.css but when I open the cquiz directory I don't see any folder called css. What did I do wrong?

Comment: sorry just to clarify when I go to cquiz/webroot I do see the css, img, and js files. I also see an error at the top "url rewriting is not properly configured" I'm guessing that's the reason

Comment: LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so was commented out in httpd.conf, I fixed that and now I see the CSS but I still don't see the images

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your documento root to cquiz/webroot.

If you are using Apache (I assume this because you said you are using WAMP) you have to edit the httpd.conf file and change the document root to your webroot directory.

Otherwise if you cannot or don't want to change the document root (let's say for example if you have another web app in the same server) you can move all the files inside webroot to your root directory and edit the index.php (which you moved from webroot to root directory) and change the `require webroot` to fit the new location.

Comment: Thanks...actually everything *looks* fine now after turning on rewrite_module, I just don't see the cake logo but when I just go to http://cakephp.org/img/cake-logo.png in my browser there's nothing there! I directed to another image and it works. At least it looks like it works.